# Import many sections of same external markdown file inside a markdown file

Tags: markdown

I have many document files in markdown, with a TOC in top and content in below. Now i want to combine all of it into one markdown file. I want all TOC of all document will in top and all content of all in below.

I try used `![...](...#...)` syntac in combine file but i cant import more than 1 section of same external document file. Ex:

```
![section1](document_1.md#section-1) - it's worked well.
```

But

```
![section1](document_1.md#section-1)

![section2](document_1.md#section-2) it's not worked.
```

The content of section 1 still appear ok, but the content of section 2 is the entire content of document_1 instead of section 2 only!!

Are there any tools which enable me to do this?